# In Android, usege of ProgressDialog.show() and ProgressDialog.hide() problem during fetching data from the internet

Tags: android, progress-bar, static-methods, pipeline, iteration

When I define progress dialog functions such as

```
    public static void showLoadingBar(Context context)
{
    dialog=new ProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
    dialog.show();
}
public static void hideLoadingBar()
{
    dialog.dismiss();

}
```

I wanna use it like following:

```
    UiManager.getInstance().showLoadingBar(this);
    FetchData();
    UiManager.getInstance().hideLoadingBar();
```

But I have never be able to show LoadingBar until I comment the 
UiManager.getInstance().hideLoadingBar(); line such like that

```
    UiManager.getInstance().showLoadingBar(this);
    FetchData();
    //UiManager.getInstance().hideLoadingBar();
```

What this cause is, always ProgressBar on the screen. Is there anyway to get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FetchData()` seems to be an asynchronous operation. So, before the actual operation is complete, the function returns and hides the loading bar. I suggest you use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

To show a progress dialog while an AsyncTask runs, you may call `show()` in `onPreExecute()` and call `hide()` in `onPostExecute()`. Call `FetchData()` from `doInBackground()`. This will start the ProgressDialog before the AsyncTask does it's background method and will stop the ProgressDialog when it completes.

Comment: second it. @Muratcan You should hide the progress bar when your `FetchData()` returns if that is an asynchronous operation.